# iOS UITableView label text becomes pixelated after scrolling and scrolling becomes slower

Tags: uitableview, ios5, uilabel, uifont

I am using a font that is not a system font for my UILabel's within my UITableCells. When I first load up the app and scroll up and down on the UITableView, it scrolls nice and smooth, but once i scroll up and down a few times it starts to get slower and slower and it seems that the font becomes a bit pixelated. Any idea what the problem could be? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a code when configuring a tableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

The font gets drawn every time the cell shows up, without clearing the Label.
Everytime the cell shows up you create a new UILabel which takes memory, especially when using custom fonts. It "redraws" the Label over and over again so the font gets pixelated/blurry.